# Explanation how this C++ template is working?

Tags: c++, templates

Am a newbie in C++, and in my endeavors in learning the language I wrote a template, and is working fine, but am puzzled how the whole thing is working!

My template contains a structure that has an operator() member function that is used as a predicate to a std::sort function. The template has an argument which is pointer to a class member, this way am able to pass different class members to be used as arguments to the template.

code:

```
// template definition

template<typename T, string T::*mp>
struct LessThan{
    inline bool operator()(const T& c1, const T& c2){
        return (c1.*mp < c2.*mp);
     }
 };

// class definition

class Person{
public:
  ...
  // fields I'll for sorting
  string first_name;
  string last_name;
};

// Somewhere in my code, create persons and fill the vector of persons
vector<Person>persons;
p1 = Person('John','Gath');
persons.push_back(p1);
...
persons.push_back(p20);

//now I want to sort my vector of persons by either frist_name or last_name

// initialize the template
LessThan<Person, &Person::first_name>lt_fname;

// my puzzle !!
std::sort(persons.begin(), persons.end(), lt_fname); //<--NOTICE, NO () when passing lt_fname

LessThan<Person, &Person::last_name>lt_lname;
std::sort(persons.begin(), persons.end(), lt_lname);  // no () for lt_lname
```

The code compiles well and runs!

What puzzles me, is my previous version for the predicate *LessThan* didn't use a template, but when passing it to sort, had to use () brackets!

How does the compiler get to know how to call the operator () function?

Paul

Comment: You created the object above with `LessThan<Person, &Person::first_name>lt_fname;` and then passed it to `std::sort`. Inside `std::sort` it will call `lt_fname()`, which is your overloaded call operator. Before you were probably creating a temporary as your predicate (e.g. `std::less<T>()` which is different to calling it which is `std::less<T>()()`). You could do `std::sort(persons.begin(), persons.end(), LessThan<Person, &Person::first_name>())` if you wanted to.

Comment: What surprises me the most is that you successfully assign a pointer to string member to a pointer to int member...

Comment: @Quentin, sorry, syntax error! editing ...

Answer (score 3):

This line:

```
// initialize the template
LessThan<Person, &Person::first_name> lt_fname;
```

does not initializes the template, but creates an instance: `lt_fname`. This instace is passed to `std::sort`. You could also do:

```
std::sort(persons.begin(), persons.end(), LessThan<Person, &Person::first_name>());
```

This time you instantiating the template on the fly, passing a temporary to the sort function.

**EDIT:** Sort might work like this:

```
template< class RandomIt, class Compare >
void sort( RandomIt first, RandomIt last, Compare comp )
{
  // assuming RandomIt a, b are two valid items, comp is called:
  auto aIsLess = comp(a, b); // it uses the operator() of `Compare`
}
```

Comment: good enough, but am wondering how sort get to know how to call () function of the LessThan struct!

Answer (score 1):

That `operator()` is the function call operator. This functionality lets you treat an object as if it were a function.

> How does the compiler get to know how to call the operator () function?

The compiler knows that your `lt_lname` is an object rather than the name of a function. Even if you did have a function named `lt_name`, your declaration of `lt_name` hides that name. The only other option is to use the object's function call operator.

The compiler doesn't "get to know this". It has to do this to be compliant with this standard.

**Update**
There are two versions of `std::sort`, one that takes two arguments that specify the range to be sorted, and another that takes an extra argument that specifies the comparison function (or functor).

The two argument version of sort uses the less than operator to compare objects. Since `operator<` can overloaded, defining `operator<` for a class provides one way of sorting a collection of instances of that class.

The three argument version takes a function (or function object) to be called in lieu of less than. Why would you do this? There are many reasons. Just a couple: Perhaps the authors of the class in question didn't define the less than operator for the class, and you can't change that class. Or perhaps you want to change the meaning of less than, depending on context. Sometimes you want to sort a collection by creation date, other times by date of last change, other times by name.

Comment: David, would this be a normal thing to do, in order to sort arbitrary class instances? It seems to be very complicated, as opposed to just defining custom sort functions.

Comment: @Greycon usually you define `operator<` and don't have to bother with custom sort predicates, but when you do using a lambda is easiest.

Comment: @Greycon - Defining a custom sort function is typically the last thing you should want to do. It's easy to write bubble sort, not to terribly hard to write a mediocre quicksort. An efficient sorting algorithm? That's non-trivial. Do you know all the nuances of sorting? Having `std::sort` means programmers who need to sort something can concentrate on areas where their skills are strongest, as can the people who know all the nuances, perils, and pitfalls of sorting.

Comment: Guys, thanks for the reply. I really meant was the idea of passing an object to the algorithm, and overriding it's () operator a standard c++ thing? Seems very convoluted to me. ( degree in comp sci , 1983 - but even then  we studied Knuth volumes 1.2 and 3 ;-)  Seriously though, I'm trying to re-acquaint myself with c++, after 20 years and guys like you who are willing to explain the finer details are a great help.